# Windows: Need to force close a process every few minutes so that batch script can start it up again

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script that starts up a process whenever it detects that the process was closed. I need to force close the process somehow on a set interval loop to see if the batch script is working as it should. What would be the best way to do this? I tried using another batch script to close the process, but didn't get the result as expected since both batch scripts open in the same command window.

Comment: Um... Use a second command window for the batch script that closes the process?

Comment: I want to automate the whole process so that I don't have to come back every few minutes and close the process so that the batch script can start it up again. That closing process is what I'm struggling with. Created a batch file that can close the process. When I call both batch files they start from the same command window.

Comment: So start your second batch from a second command window. It's only for testing, right?  So you can open two command windows for the testing process. Launch your restart batch file from the first command window, switch to the second command window, and start your close process batch. Then walk away. Windows is perfectly capable of running two separate command windows at the same time, both doing different things.

Comment: Have you considered rewriting your process as a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx)? Seems like a more reliable way to make sure a particular hunk of code is running.

Answer (score 0):

In a second script, loop with `goto` and use a `ping` for pause.

```
:loop
:: 301 = 5 minutes.  The first ping response is instant.
ping -n 301 0.0.0.0 >NUL
taskkill /im "program.exe" /f
goto loop
```

Comment: Just curious - why use `ping` instead of `timeout`?

Comment: Old habit, and for [more universal compatibility](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html).